# How are cells that have died replaced by new ones?

Tags: cell-biology, death, cell-division

I'd like to have a clearer picture how cells that have died are replaced by new ones.

I assume the following:

- Normally, when a cell dies it will be replaced by a new one of the same type.
- It will be replaced by the division of another cell (of the same or another type). One copy remains where it is and keeps its type (for later use) and the other one possibly travels to its target location (where the died one has lived) and possibly changes its type (during travel or after arrival).

My questions are:

- Are these assumptions essentially correct? Or are they overly simplified?
- What are possible distances between the regenerating dividing cell and the target location? I assume some static cells will be replaced in situ, possibly skin cells. Others may be regenerated far away, especially floating cells, like blood cells.
- If the distance is large: How does the regenerating cell know it has to divide? And how does the regenerated copy know where to travel to?
- When one of the copies of the regenerating cell starts to travel,why doesn't the other?
- Are there cases where the regenerating cell is already of the same type as the cell that has died – and so are its two copies?
- What about the (programmed) lifetimes of the regenerating cells?

I hope these questions - which would give me *one* consistent picture - can be answered in *one* comprehensive answer.